# How can I find a Fraisse's paper

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

I want to see Fraisse's "Sur certaines relations qui généralisent l’order des nombres rationnels". But at https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3188h, the search returns nothing. I wonder how to find this paper.

Comment: Your link is for volume 236; I think you want vol. 237.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3189t/f540.item.r=fraisse). (EDIT: as kimchi lover comments, the issue seems to be that you want volume $237$ instead of $236$.)

Note that the "paper" itself, if this is indeed the right citation, seems to really just be an announcement of results.

Comment: How does one search on Gallica?  It was not at all clear to me how to do what you did.